# Yocto gcc cannot find reference to function from shared library

Tags: include, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake

I have written a package containing 3 files : foo.c, foo.h and README.TXT. Here is the recipe :

```
DESCRIPTION = "foo Drivers"
#To prevent the LICENSE field not set
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "file://foo.c \
       file://foo.h \
           file://README.txt"

FILES_${PN} += "${incdir}/foo.h"

do_compile() {
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${WORKDIR}/foo.c -o foo
}

do_install() {
        install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir} ${D}${docdir}/foo ${D}${incdir}
        install -m 0755 ${S}/foo ${D}${bindir}
        install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/README.txt ${D}${docdir}/foo
        install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/foo.h ${D}${incdir}
}
```

But when I do `bitbake foo` I have this error :

```
WARNING: foo-0.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: foo: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /foo.h
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
foo: 1 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
```

And because of this, in an another package depending on foo, when I add in the recipe : `DEPENDS = "foo"`, I have this error :

```
fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory
```

The error is from the line `#include <foo.h>`.

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT:**

```
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/foo.h ${D}${includedir}
```

Resolved the warning problem but I still have :

```
fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory
```

When I want to compile a package depending on foo.h

**EDIT2:**
I have changed the bblayer of my foo package to create a .so shared library, like so :

```
DESCRIPTION = "foo driver"
#To prevent the LICENSE field not set
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
PR = "r70"

SRC_URI = "file://foo.c \
           file://foo.h \
           file://README.txt"

CFLAGS_append =" -fPIC -g -c -Wall "

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/* ${libdir}/pkgconfig/*"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${WORKDIR}/foo.c -o foo
    ${CC} -shared -Wl,-soname,${WORKDIR}/libfoo.so.1 \
        -o ${WORKDIR}/libfoo.so.1.0.1 foo -lc

}

do_install() {

    install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir} ${D}${libdir} ${D}${docdir}/foo ${D}${includedir} ${D}${libdir}/pkgconfig
    install -m 0755 ${S}/foo ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/README.txt ${D}${docdir}/foo
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/foo.h ${D}${includedir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/libfoo.so.1.0.1 ${D}${libdir}
    ldconfig -n ${D}${libdir}
}
```

But in my Test package, even if I add `#include <foo.h>` and `DEPENDS = "pjproject gpio"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "gpio"` I have `error: undefined reference to` function coming from `foo.h`. here is my test bblayer :

```
DESCRIPTION = "test"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PR = "r2"

SRC_URI = "file://main.c \
           file://Makefile \
           file://README.txt"

S = "${WORKDIR}/"

DEPENDS = "gpio"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "gpio"


do_compile() {
        cd ${S}
        oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
        install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir} ${D}${docdir}/test
        install -m 0755 ${S}/test ${D}${bindir}
        install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/README.txt ${D}${docdir}/test
}
```

And if I add `-lfoo` in my Makefile, I have `/bin/sh: 1: -lfoo: not found`.

Why ? thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3):

```
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/foo.h ${D}${incdir}
```

this should be

```
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/foo.h ${D}${includedir}
```

You can see in the QA warning message how your header got installed into `/` instead of `/usr/include/`.

You should also remove the FILES_{PN} line: it's wrong (because headers go into -dev package) and not needed as the right thing should be done by default.

Comment: Thank you, `${D}${includedir}` is the solution for my `bitbake foo` problem. But I still have the `fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory`...

Comment: Any idea? For my remaining problem?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong in the post... I would take a look at the actual compile output (should be in $WORKDIR/temp/log.do_compile) -- does it have the target sysroot as an include dir. I would also look at the sysroot directory and double check that the header has been installed in there. On yocto master the sysroot is in $WORKDIR/recipe-sysroot/ (it's built specifically for this recipe) but on older releases they are in $TMPDIR/sysroots/<arch>/ (these are common sysroots shared by all recipes).

Comment: Thank you, I had to add `#include <linux/foo.h>` instead of `#include <foo.h>` even if I change `install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/foo.h ${D}${includedir}` to `install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/foo.h ${D}/usr/include` but I have a linker problem. I have the `error: undefined reference to` all the functions in foo.h I call in my main.c...

Comment: soo foo.h exposes functions? Are you aware that your recipe does not install any libraries?

Comment: Yes foo.h exposes functions. "Are you aware that your recipe does not install any libraries?" --> So what am I doing wrong ? Isn't this the good steps? I have a working lib foo, and I just want to use functions declared in this lib.

Comment: Your compile step seems to currently compile a binary, not a shared library. Maybe take a look at a howto like this one: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: I have added an **EDIT2:** to my question. Thank you for you help.